# How to write powershell output to file? [Python]

Tags: python, powershell

I am having this problem where I can print out the powershell code output with the print() function, but when I try to do the same, except this time I write the output to a file, the only thing that is written in the file is "0", why would the printed output be different from when I write the same exact code, except that I this time "print" it to a text file.

I want the text file to contain exactly what the print function prints to the terminal, why isn't it working, and how can I get it to work??
Here are some pictures and the code:

```
import os
import time
def monitorprocess(process):
    run = True

    time_q = float(input("How many minutes before each check? "))
    while run:
        
        timespan = os.system(f'powershell New-TimeSpan -Start(Get-process {process}).StartTime')
        try:
            open(f'powershellpython\{process}.txt','x')
        except:
            pass
        with open(f'powershellpython\{process}.txt',"w") as file:
            file.write(str(timespan))
        print(timespan)

        time.sleep(time_q*60)

def processes():
    process = input("What is the name of your process, if you are unsure, type 'get-process', and if you want to use ID (this works with multiple processes with the same name) type ID: \n")
    if process == "get-process":
        print(os.system("powershell get-process"))
        process = input("What is the name of your process, if you are unsure, type 'get-process', and find your process: \n")
    else:
        monitorprocess(process)
processes()
```

[image: output]
[image: output in text document]

And there is some more output with the print, that being "hours" and "days", but that does not really matter in this context.

Comment: maybe you should do `python script.py > output.txt` - and probably it should redirect console output to file (at least it works in `cmd.exe` or `bash` on Linux). OR you should use other functions in module `subprocess` - like `subprocess.run()` or [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) because with `os.system()` you can't catch output.

Comment: @furas Ok, I will try that out!

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it with `powershell` because I don't use `Windows` but to catch output you should use other methods in `subprocess`

ie. [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
 import subprocess

 output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

 with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(output.decode())
```

ie. [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

```
 import subprocess
 from subprocess import PIPE

 output = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout

 with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(output.decode())
```

---

Probably you could even redirect `run()` directly to file using `stdout=`

```
 with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
     subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=file)
```

---

Using `os.system()` you can catch only `return code` (`error code`) and you could only do `python script.py > output.txt` to get text in file `output.txt`

Comment: subprocess.run() worked for me, thx.

Answer (score 0):

What you see on screen can be produced by PowerShell.

Try

```
timespan = os.system(f'powershell New-TimeSpan -Start(Get-process {process}).StartTime | Format-List | Out-String')
```

This now will not return a TimeSpan **object**, but rather a multiline **string** meant to display the properties of the object on screen.

Comment: In python I get an error stating: 'Format-List' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
255
The same goes for Out-String

Although it works in normal Powershell, outside of python

Comment: @NoteSalad I have escaped the pipe characters now. Can you try again please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with python, so I have no idea if you need to escape the pipe characters or not (apparently not..). Perhaps you need to do some more quoting or as @furas suggests, an entirely different way to run a powershell command from python.

Comment: yup, seems like it, thanks for the help htough!